# Hyper-V Get-VM in powershell via asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to write a web interface that will show the current VMs on a remote Hyper-V host.

So far, I have this

```
    protected void getVMS(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //command to run
        string cmdToRun = "get-vm -computername fsyovs02";

        var shell = PowerShell.Create();

        shell.Commands.AddScript(cmdToRun);

        var results = shell.Invoke();

           if (results.Count > 0)
           {

              var builder = new StringBuilder();

              foreach (PSObject vm in results)
              {

                  builder.Append(vm.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
              }

            ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
          }
    }
```

This is returning something, but not what I want.  For each VM, it is returning the line

```
  Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine
```

What I want is it to display exactly how it does via powershell.

Can anyone help me please - as I am going out of my mind!

Many Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry had to edit my answer as you cannot access those types from C#. You should then use the Members collection on PSObject to access particular properties of the VirtualMachine. Please check this approach in your case:

```
    foreach (PSObject vm in results)
    {       
           builder.Append(vm.Members["Name"].Value + "\r\n");
    }
```

Comment: What namespace do I need to be using for that to work - as when I try it the 'Hyper-V' bit of the cast says it is not available in the namespace.  And also, many thanks for your response.

Comment: Just updated my answer. As the previous approach will not work in your case

Comment: That worked beautifully, and is exactly what I was after.  Thanks very much.  If I had more reputation i'd give you an upvote!